# C++ std::vector inserting two elements alternative algorithm fails

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, stl, stdvector

In my project, I needed to insert two elements into two indices. I was implementing an alternative implementation instead of vector insert since two insert calls shift vector elements twice and I can do the same with a single shift. However, the alternative is far slower. What could be the explanation of this behavior?

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

void insert2(std::vector<int>& items, size_t first, size_t last, int item = -1) {
    // assert(last < items.size() + 2);
    // assert(first < last);
    // assert(0 <= first);
    // Creating two temporary objects
    // items.reserve(std::max(items.capacity(), items.size() + 2));
    items.emplace_back(); items.emplace_back();

    // Moving elements from the back to last
    for(auto p = items.end() - 1, q = items.begin() + last; p != q; --p) {
        // *p = std::move(*(p - 2));
        *p = *(p - 2);
    }
    // Emplace at last
    // new(&items[last]) ...
    items[last] = item;
    // Moving elements from last to first
    for(auto p = items.begin() + last - 1, q = items.begin() + first; p != q; --p) {
        // *p = std::move(*(p - 1));
        *p = *(p - 1);
    }
    // Emplace at first
    // new(&items[first]) ...
    items[first] = item;
}

auto now() {
    return std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
}

int main() {
    const size_t N = 100;
    const size_t M = 100;
    auto begin = now();

    begin = now();
    for(size_t n = 0; n < N; n++) { // run the same N times
        for(size_t i = 0; i < M + 1; i++) {
            for(size_t j = i + 1; j < M + 2; j++) {
                std::vector<int> v(M);
                insert2(v, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "insert2 " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(now() - begin).count() / (1000.0 * N) << "us\n";

    begin = now();
    for(size_t n = 0; n < N; n++) { // run the same N times 
        for(size_t i = 0; i < M + 1; i++) {
            for(size_t j = i + 1; j < M + 2; j++) {
                std::vector<int> v(M);
                v.insert(v.begin() + i, -1);
                v.insert(v.begin() + j, -1);
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "insert1 " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(now() - begin).count() / (1000.0 * N) << "us\n";
}
```

My  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz outputs with O0

```
insert2 7941.29us
insert1 4005.15us
```

With O3,

```
insert2 763.64us
insert1 688.365us
```

[`Live demo on quick-bench`](http://quick-bench.com/-dN7RpffBPIMepOnnxOfJ-z7FLM)

Comment: note that `std::vector::insert` has overloads to insert more than a single element, eg overload 5 here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

Comment: see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5470596)

Comment: @YSC this is just testing code. I would never include that header

Comment: then why did you include it here? also I wonder what `DODO` is good for, other than obfuscation ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 overload 5's second argument is an initializer list. Isn't it?

Comment: yes, meaning you can pass any number of elements to be inserted

Comment: I still do not get you. I think you get my intentions. How else should I test my method? @formerlyknownas_463035818

Comment: I am talking about the overload

Comment: meh sorry, I misread the question and wrongly assumed you want to insert into adjacent indices

Comment: It is ok. But I do not understand the behavior still.

Comment: And btw guys, please focus on the actual problem instead of coding practices. This is not how I program. I am just calculating elapsed times. These code segments are straight taken from my testing headers.

Comment: @IsuraManchanayake very hard too when the code is riddled with macros, you must know you should never use them.

Comment: to understand the actual problem we need to read your code and using strange macros is not helping for readability. Its not about being picky about style but about real struggle when I see `DODO(N)` and have to search your code to understand what it means, thats all...

Comment: Ok. I would update the code. Please wait.

Comment: Hopefully, it is readable by now. Please go through and tell if anything is unreadable.

Comment: With `-O0`? You need to enable optimizations if you measure performance. Profiling non-optimized builds makes no sense.

Comment: I have already attached the O3 performance differences

Comment: I've added [`live demo`](http://quick-bench.com/-dN7RpffBPIMepOnnxOfJ-z7FLM).

Comment: @DanielLangr not sure if I did that correctly, but [it is a bit faster](http://quick-bench.com/8UiNkPH1VxsauIJ6qinjlqoXS9I). Unit test are needed to verify this.

Comment: I expect the slowness is simply because you're copying all the elements individually. std::vector most likely does a single memmove for everything after the insertion point.

Comment: @MarekR I also did an experiment with your benchmark and a much larger vector plus avoiding reallocations, and then your custom version [gets faster](http://quick-bench.com/Xr8I4zkWdqg-3htYUTUD0MyqiH0). Additionally, I created a special benchmark to completely avoid allocations and the custom versions [are faster as well there](http://quick-bench.com/bAPXi7U17Xc90mtqXBuwrW_7usE).

Answer (score 2):

I used a benchmark created by @MarekR and modified it such that no (re)allocations happen inside the benchmark loop, see http://quick-bench.com/UX9aEcrP06xBe51qKX3LjZWMU38. Then I did only a single double-insertion to the 1/3 and 2/3 of the vector size. With a vector of 100 integer elements (constant `N`), the custom version is actually slower, however, for 1000 elements it's already faster. And, for 1M elements, the custom version is almost exactly 1.5 times faster, which corresponds with the number of spared elements *"moves"*. With `std::vector::insert`, you need to move `N` elements, while with a custom version only `N * 2 / 3`.

To be honest, I still don't know why the custom version is slower for small vectors. Anyway, I think you might be interested in this answer as well.

Comment: Thank you. Although it is a bit different from my use case.